# Read and Answer the Question

Tags: pattern

Which name does not belong on this list?

> Charles Darwin
>   Anthony Burgess
>   Edward Albee
>   Alice Munro
>   Ignatius of Loyola
>   Phyllis Schlafly

First hint:
You actually don't need any hints

Second hint:
Six

Third hint:
If you have any doubts or debates concerning your answer, it is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: This *almost* seems too broad to me, but the solution is obvious in retroscpect so +1.

Comment: I don't get the second hint even after reading the answer (two other hints are fine).

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev think legs.

Comment: @Deusovi The hints were more about "too broad" concerns than any need for hints.

Comment: @Hugh: General consensus [on meta](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4559/should-we-flag-a-riddle-as-too-broad-without-looking-at-the-hints?cb=1) was that hints are not enough to keep puzzles from being too broad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's either

> Ignatius of Loyola, because there are three words there instead of two,

or

> Phyllis Schlafly, because it's misspelled.

OK, I know that's not the real answer

It's

> Charles Darwin, because all the others have a bug in the name:
>
>  **Ant**hony Burgess
>  Edward Al**bee**
>  A**lice** Munro
>  I**gnat**ius of Loyola
>  Phyllis Schla**fly**

Comment: I'll let this go this time, @GentlePurpleRain...

Comment: That edit got you my plus one.

Answer (score 6):

#### This is not the intended answer of OP

I (don't) hope it is

> **Anthony Burgess**

because

> Only his name doesn't have letter ***L***
>  CHAR**L**ES DARWIN
>  Anthony Burgess
>  EDWARD A**L**BEE
>  A**L**ICE MUNRO
>  IGNATIUS of **L**OYO**L**A
>  PHY**LL**IS SCH**L**AF**L**Y